# scraping text between first space and question mark

Tags: python, regex

I have data in particular format like this:

```
Alessandro_Volta    Was Alessandro Volta a professor of chemistry?  Alessandro Volta was not a professor of chemistry.  easy    easy    data/set4/a10
Alessandro_Volta    Was Alessandro Volta a professor of chemistry?  No  easy    hard    data/set4/a10
Alessandro_Volta    Did Alessandro Volta invent the remotely operated pistol?   Alessandro Volta did invent the remotely operated pistol.   easy    easy    data/set4/a10
Alessandro_Volta    Did Alessandro Volta invent the remotely operated pistol?   Yes easy    easy    data/set4/a10
Alessandro_Volta    Was Alessandro Volta taught in public schools?  Volta was taught in public schools. easy    easy    data/set4/a10
Alessandro_Volta    Was Alessandro Volta taught in public schools?  Yes easy    easy    data/set4/a10
```

I want to scrap `question` out of this. i.e. text between `first \t` and `?` (i thought of this solution, dont know if better one)

import re

```
def f(regexStr,target):
    mo = re.search(regexStr,target)
    if not mo:
        print "NO MATCH"
    else:
        print "MATCH:",mo.group()

f(r"\^[^~]*~","{Mat^chThisT~ext}")
```

this code correctly give text between `^` and `~`, but same I tried for `\t` and `?`, it give `NO MATCH`.

Comment: If this is your use case, why not use `if '?' in word`? or to be more specific, `'?' == word[-1]`

Comment: Note that `?` means something specific in regular expressions

Comment: @ReutSharabani or `word.endswith('?')`.

Comment: didn't know it exists :) on the other hand I do know `startswith`... makes sense

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I did not get you. can you please elaborate? I can match `?` but what should be other end to be matched?

Comment: If this is tab separated you actually shouldn't (I thought you only want the word with `?` next to it). You can `split` on `\t` and take the value on index `1` of the split result. An answer was added that seems to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the input is consistently formatted, then why not something simple like:

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    questions = [line.split('\t', 2)[1].strip() for line in input_file]
```

Assuming the question part of each line in the `input.txt` file is always preceded and followed by a `tab` character, `questions` will contain a list of strings consisting of the questions.

Comment: You might as well also make it `line.split('\t', 2)[1]` to reduce the amount of splitting as you're not interested in splitting elements further than that

Comment: True, though given the sample input I'm not sure you'll notice much of difference in performance?

Comment: It's about 40% faster limiting the split :)

Comment: I was just thinking, if it runs in less than a second on the likely inputs, does saving fractions of a second matter? But you're right, and it's a better practice anyway, so I've editted to add.

Comment: Hope you don't mind - I've edited to remove the `rb` from the `open` as 1) it should have been a string literal, and 2) it should really be opened in text mode and as read and text is the default, the argument can be omitted anyway...

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[ ]{4,}).*?\?
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/36

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=[ ]{4,}).*?\?')
test_str = "Alessandro_Volta Was Alessandro Volta a professor of chemistry? Alessandro Volta was not a professor of chemistry. easy easy data/set4/a10\nAlessandro_Volta Was Alessandro Volta a professor of chemistry? No easy hard data/set4/a10\nAlessandro_Volta Did Alessandro Volta invent the remotely operated pistol? Alessandro Volta did invent the remotely operated pistol. easy easy data/set4/a10\nAlessandro_Volta Did Alessandro Volta invent the remotely operated pistol? Yes easy easy data/set4/a10\nAlessandro_Volta Was Alessandro Volta taught in public schools? Volta was taught in public schools. easy easy data/set4/a10\nAlessandro_Volta Was Alessandro Volta taught in public schools? Yes easy easy data/set4/a10"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the question, as `' '*4` != `'\t'`. Also fails to match only the first such pattern.

Comment: @selllikesybok this does answer the question.see demo.

Comment: you match all text preceded by `4 or more spaces` and followed by a `?`. The question asks for matching on the first occurence of text preceded by a `tab` and followed by a `?`. In the test you linked to, the pattern matches all occurences, not just the first, and as I noted, matches on spaces, not tabs. Not sure how you can say it answers the question?